# How to put default_url_option for specific path only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `defaul_url_option` for putting `lang params` in my url e.g. `home/?lang=en`, However some of my ajax function is not working because of the parameter `lang` added to the `url request`, How to specify only in specific path or routes

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should even not touch the lang param in any of your routes, unless you want to change your language.

Your app controller should have:

```
  def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    { lang: I18n.locale }
  end
```

and you routes.rb:

```
  scope "/(:lang)", :lang => /de|en/ do
    # resources definitions
  end
```

Now, in any of your route you do not need provide lang param (unless you want to switch language), it is generated out of the box.